# How to create a d3 table from complex dictionary

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

[Table look I'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcGDG.png)I'm trying to make a table using JavaScript or D3.js.  The table needs to be indexed by assignments and the headers to be each individual student.

I have tried using different iterators like .forEach .map .keys... etc... My two dictionaries right now are assignments and students

My current mess /yikes
https://github.com/zogzmiller/BCSapitesting/blob/master/apitesting/fetchscript.js

```
Original API call IE gradesData Object

0: {assignmentTitle: "0: Data Prework", studentName: "Amanda Belloma", submitted: true, grade: "A+"}
1: {assignmentTitle: "0: Data Prework", studentName: "Andrew Nesbit", submitted: true, grade: "A+"}
2: {assignmentTitle: "0: Data Prework", studentName: "Arjun Nanje Gowda", submitted: true, grade: "A+"}
3: {assignmentTitle: "0: Data Prework", studentName: "Christina Clements", submitted: true, grade: "A+"}
4: {assignmentTitle: "0: Data Prework", studentName: "Dakota Mason", submitted: true, grade: "A+"}
5: {assignmentTitle: "0: Data Prework", studentName: "Dallas Diaz", submitted: true, grade: "A+"}
.....
60: {assignmentTitle: "D3.js Homework", studentName: "Peter Broll", submitted: false, grade: null}
61: {assignmentTitle: "D3.js Homework", studentName: "Regina Neitzey", submitted: false, grade: null}
62: {assignmentTitle: "D3.js Homework", studentName: "Richard Walter", submitted: false, grade: null}
63: {assignmentTitle: "D3.js Homework", studentName: "Rudolph Nartker", submitted: false, grade: null}
64: {assignmentTitle: "D3.js Homework", studentName: "Sir-Lee Thompson", submitted: false, grade: null}
65: {assignmentTitle: "D3.js Homework", studentName: "Timothy Raynor", submitted: false, grade: null}
66: {assignmentTitle: "ETL Project", studentName: "Amanda Belloma", submitted: false, grade: null}
67: {assignmentTitle: "ETL Project", studentName: "Andrew Nesbit", submitted: false, grade: null}
68: {assignmentTitle: "ETL Project", studentName: "Arjun Nanje Gowda", submitted: false, grade: null}
69: {assignmentTitle: "ETL Project", studentName: "Christina Clements", submitted: false, grade: null}
70: {assignmentTitle: "ETL Project", studentName: "Dakota Mason", submitted: false, grade: null}
71: {assignmentTitle: "ETL Project", studentName: "Dallas Diaz", submitted: false, grade: null}
72: {assignmentTitle: "ETL Project", studentName: "Daniel Ruch", submitted: false, grade: null}

Converted into this Dictionary
Gradesdict = 0: Data Prework: Array(22)
0: {student: "Amanda Belloma", grade: "A+"}
1: {student: "Andrew Nesbit", grade: "A+"}
2: {student: "Arjun Nanje Gowda", grade: "A+"}
3: {student: "Christina Clements", grade: "A+"}
4: {student: "Dakota Mason", grade: "A+"}
5: {student: "Dallas Diaz", grade: "A+"}
6: {student: "Daniel Ruch", grade: "A+"}
7: {student: "Jamie Lewis", grade: "A+"}
8: {student: "Jason Morris", grade: "A+"}
9: {student: "Jeffrey Goodman", grade: null}
10: {student: "John Hooser", grade: null}
11: {student: "John Watt", grade: "A+"}
12: {student: "Kevin Brown", grade: "A+"}
13: {student: "Logan Bird", grade: "A+"}
14: {student: "Luis Coca Urdanivia", grade: "A+"}
15: {student: "Michael Robben", grade: "A+"}
16: {student: "Peter Broll", grade: "A+"}
17: {student: "Regina Neitzey", grade: "Incomplete"}
18: {student: "Richard Walter", grade: "A+"}
19: {student: "Rudolph Nartker", grade: null}
20: {student: "Sir-Lee Thompson", grade: null}
21: {student: "Timothy Raynor", grade: "A+"}

d3.select("tbody")
.selectAll("th")
.data(keys) 
.enter()
.append("tr")
.html(function(d) {
    return `<tr>${d}</tr>`;
});
d3.select("thead")
.selectAll("th")
.data(stukeys)
.enter()
.append("th")
.html(function(d) {
    return `<tr>${d}</tr>`;
});
```

this gives me the a row for each assignemnt, IE row1 is 0:Data Prework and all of my headers are each students name.  Having trouble getting the grades to align with everything. plz halp

Comment: Why do you want to use d3js?

Comment: If it can be done in plain JavaScript that would be amazing!  I'm just most familiar with D3 tables/layout

Comment: "I have tried using different iterators like .forEach .map .keys... etc..." - can you include what youve tried. How is the data formatted when you are accessing it via JS?

Comment: I just posted my repo, it's through a private API which makes this difficult.  Updating post to show original API call.

Comment: If you log the data after it has returned from the call then you can see the actual json response

Comment: @LoganMiller do you want a table for each student with each assignment as an entry or grouped per assignment with the student the entry?

Comment: updated post to show json response.  My idea is to iterate through gradedict to get a new row for each assignment, adding td's for each student's grade.  Mostly getting caught up when it only prints [object, Object] for each <td>.

Comment: @vince I added an image, pretty sure grouped per assignment with the student headers/entries